# cannot load component in react/redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

when i go to
/posts/:id i should load the PostItem component from the Post component.My instructor in Udemy course has no such problem

Post.js

```
const Post = ({getPost,post:{post,loading},match}) => {
useEffect(()=>{
    getPost(match.params.id)
},[getPost])

return (loading ||post===null ? <Spinner/>:( <Fragment>
<PostItem post={post} showActions={false}/>
</Fragment>)
)
}
```

howwever I get this error
[image]

the problem is that when i replace PostItem with anything else like test ,everything is working fine all the actions and working

Also the PostItem is used for loading another component so dont know whats causing the problem

Comment: The error is whereever you are using `_id`, which is not in the code you posted.

Comment: the _id is coming from state when action GET_POST is passed. when i replace PostItem with something like <h1>hello<.h1> the post state is returned with proper _id. why doesnt PostItem cannot read it ???

Comment: however with PostItem none of my actions work like GET_POST

Answer (score 0):

solved my problem by adding post && before the component

```
{ post && <PostItem post={post} showActions={false}/>}
```

BUT i dont know why it worked for my instructor who did not add post aka wait post for be to be loaded ???